# Complement of the union of countably many , mutually disjoint , non-empty open balls in $\mathbb R^n , (n >1) $ is path connected?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $n \ge 2$ and $\{B_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ be countably infinitely many , mutually disjoint , non-empty  open balls in $\mathbb R^n$ , then is $\mathbb R^n \setminus \cup_{m=1}^\infty B_m$ path-connected ?

Comment: Does there exist a non-countable set of disjoint open balls in $\Bbb R^n$? I'd say not, since $\Bbb R^n$ is a contable union of compact sets.

Comment: @ajotatxe Now that you mention it, I note that my answer doesn't explicitly use that the index set is only countable ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Let $B_m$ be the open ball of radius $r_m$ around $(x_m,y_m)$. 
It suffices to consider the case $n=2$ and here to show that there exists a path from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ (assuming wlog. that these points are in the set).
The obvious attempt is the curve $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (t,0)$, but for each disk it intersects we need to take a detour along the boundary of the disk. So try this $t\mapsto (t,f(t))$ instead, where
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}y_m+\sqrt{r_m^2-(t-x_m)^2}&\text{if $(t,0)\in B_m$ and $y_m\le 0$}\\
y_m-\sqrt{r_m^2-(t-x_m)^2}&\text{if $(t,0)\in B_m$ and $y_m> 0$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
This is well-defined (because $(t,0)$ can be inside at most one $B_m$), clearly continuous, and avoids all $B_m$ (again per their open disjointness).
Additionally, it turns out that this path is rectifyable and of length at most $\pi$ (or in the general case: $\pi$ times the straight distance).

Comment: what is $x_m , y_m$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev It seems that $B_m$ is the $m$th open ball with center at $(x_m,y_m)$ and radius $r_m$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks, I added that